# Little o for sequences as a subspace of $c$: closed or not?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $g=(g_n)$ be a convergent sequence of reals and define $o(g)$ as the set of all sequences $x=(x_n)$ of reals where for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_n|\leq \epsilon |g_n|$ for all $n\geq N$. Then $o(g)$ is a subset of $c$, the space of convergent sequences of reals. In fact, every element of $o(g)$ converges to zero, provided $\lim_n g_n <\infty$, as we assume.

**Question**: is $o(g)$ (as defined here) closed in $(c, \|\cdot \|_\infty)$ i.e. under the norm $\sup_n |x_n|$?

If $g$ is a sequence such that $|g_n|/(1+|g_n|)$ is bounded below by some $K>0$ for all $n$ then it follows. But this is somewhat an artificial condition I think and I have not found others yet nor counterexamples.

Comment: If $g$ is convergent and if $x \in o(g)$ according to the standard def'n of $o(g)$ then $x$ converges to $0$, so $x\in c$. So your def'n of $o(g)$, for $g\in c,$ is exactly equivalent to the standard def'n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For convergent $g$ we have: $o(g)$ is closed iff $g$ does not converge to $0.$

(I). Suppose $g=(g_n)_n$ converges to $0.$ Let $x^{(j)}_n=|g_n|+\frac {1}{n}$ if $n\le j,$ and $x^{(j)}_n=0$ if $n>j.$ And let $x^{(j)}=(x^{(j)}_n)_n$. Then $(x^{(j)})_j$ is a sequence in $o(g)$ converging in norm to $(|g_n|+\frac {1}{n})_n\not \in o(g).$

(II). Suppose $g_n$ converges  to $L\ne 0.$ Let $K=\frac {|L|/2}{1+|L|}$ and let $h_n=g_n $ if $\frac {|g_n|}{1+|g_n|}\ge K,$ otherwise let $h_n=L.$ Then $h=(h_n)_n$ is convergent (to $L$)  and $\frac {|h_n|}{1+|h_n|}\ge K>0$ for all $n.$ Your result that $o(h)$ is closed implies that $o(g$) is closed, because $\{n:h_n\ne g_n\}$ is finite, so $o(h)=o(g).$

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you. Just to be sure, (I) shows that $o(g)$ is closed implies $g$ does not vanish in its limit via contraposition, correct?

Comment: yes....................

Comment: I thought of something else: Let $F(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n$ for $x=(x_n)_n\in c. $ Then $F:c\to \Bbb R$ is linear. And also continuous because $|F(x)-F(y)|=|F(x-y)|\le \|x-y\|.$ Now for $any$ $g\in c$ with $F(g)\ne 0$ we have $o(g)=F^{-1}\{0\}, $ which is closed because $F$ is continuous..... On the other hand if $F(g)=0$  my A shows that $o(g)$ is a non-closed subset of $F^{-1}\{0\}.$

Comment: oh wow this is a nice way to see it! (And does not require my little lemma) Thanks again.